# SMB network shares frequently disconnecting & failing to reconnect

Tags: macos, file-sharing, smb, network-user

Late 2013 iMac running 10.9.2, authenticated to Open Directory and Active Directory, connecting to SMB shares hosted on multiple Windows server file shares.  Connected to the network via ethernet.  Many other Macs (15-20) are connecting to many of the same shares without the issues I describe below.

Immediately after boot and login I can access all of the appropriate shares for my user account, everything I have permission to see.  After a while, the timing is inconsistent though usually 10 minutes will do it, the shares seem to disconnect.  If I click on a share from the desktop it hangs and the share disappears.

At this point if I hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (connect to server) and attempt to reconnect or browse out to another share (by going to smb://server/ and looking through the available shares) the window disappears when I click connect but nothing else happens.  No connection is made.

If I try 10 times I *might* get lucky and reconnect but shortly go back to the starting point, where it eventually disconnects again.

Connecting to shares using my same credentials on a different Mac works fine and the connections seem to stay active.

I've already removed com.apple.sidebarlist.plist from ~/Library/Preferences, then rebooted, but the issue has persisted.

When the issue is occurring and I attempt to connect to any share I see the following line in Console.app:

> 5/22/14 3:03:53.846 PM NetAuthSysAgent[27844]: smb_mount: mount failed to server1/thefileshare, syserr = Invalid argument

The same time that I'm unable to connect I've tried running extended (100~) ping tests to the servers and they finish with no packet loss and low latency.  Trying to connect while I'm successfully pinging the servers still fails.

Any ideas?